# how to create buttons using for loop in python using in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make TIC TAC TOE game using GUI for different numbers of blocks which is to be taken by the user as an input.So how can i make different number of buttons ?

Comment: What did you already try (code)? Can you give us an example of what you want (image)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create 3 x 3 buttons you can use the Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager for placing them ( see [Tkinter Grid manager doc](http://The%20Tkinter%20Grid%20Geometry%20Manager) ).
Just do something like ( Pseude Code ):

```
master = Tk()
buttons = []
for curRow in range(3):
  for curCol in range(3):
    b = Button( master, ... )
    b.grid(row=curRow, column=curCol)
    buttons.append( b )
```

This should create a Tic-Tac-Toe-grid.

Comment: This will create a list that looks like `[None, None, None, None, ...]`

Comment: It will? Could you give me a hint why?

Comment: instead of col try out column

Comment: Now i would like to ask that how could i access each button created by the above method.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk(  )
for r in range(3):
    for c in range(4):
        Tkinter.Button(root, text='R%s/C%s'%(r,c),
            borderwidth=1 ).grid(row=r,column=c)
root.mainloop(  )`
```

Comment: This looks the same as the other answer. If you're trying to say something different, could you add an explanation of what it is?